# Steam API: How to get players in current game?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm wondering if there is anyway to get the current players in someone's Steam game.
For example when your in-game, you can go into the Steam Menu and click "View Players" to see players in your current game and recent games.

I can't find any answers to this on the internet. Is this even possible with Steam's API? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

I think this can help you:

https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?appid={the id of the game without braces}

[How to get the game ID](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3729-WFJZ-4175)